# why python read informaton in file but not it's content?

Tags: python

I try to Python read and then print text from file score.txt (in score.txt is text hrllo world) i write this command:

```
score = open("data/score.txt", "r")
print(score)
```

and output is:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='data/score.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1250'>
```

how can i print "hello world" from file score.txt?

Comment: try `print(score.read())`

Comment: An open file has a method literally named ``read``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to read the whole filo into the variable in your case.

```
score = open("data/score.txt", "r").read()
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

I also offer some unsolicited advice: I recommend using a so-called context manager which will automatically close the file after you're done using it (even in case reading the file fails for some reason).

```
with open("data/score.txt", "r") as score_file:
    print(score_file.read())
```

This is not really very important in your case, but it is an accepted best practice and should be followed whenever possible.